# Setup reason codes for setupTestcase in Unit Test Framework [AX 2012]

Tags: unit-testing, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am using reason code entries in a Dialog form.

For writing the unit Test for the above, I need to first insert reasonCodes dynamically via code in setUpTestCase in UnitTestFramework in Dynamics AX 2012.

How can I do this? I havnt found any help on the internet yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Self learned the answer.*

In order to write a Unit Test using UnitTestFramework, you create a class which extends SysTestCase class (a System class).

**setUp(), setUpTestCase(), tearDown(), tearDownTestCase() are base class functions which are used for setting up and destroying the data during purposely for the test case.**

setUp() & tearDown() methods are called at the start & end respectively for each test function in the test case class.
**Note, setUp(), tearDown() is run once for every test function while setUpTestCase(), tearDownTestCase() is run only once for for a unit test at the start and end respectively.**

---

*Coming back to what I asked,
I had to `setup reason codes` together with reason comments for writing the test case.*

**Following is the X++ code required to do so.**

```
private void createReason(str _reasonCode, str _reasonComment)
{
    ReasonTable         _reasonTable;

    _reasonTable.clear();
    _reasonTable.Asset = NoYes::Yes;
    _reasonTable.Ledger = NoYes::Yes;
    _reasonTable.Reason = _reasonCode;
    _reasonTable.Description = _reasonComment;

    _reasonTable.doInsert();
}
```

You might have different setting to setup reasons in your test case.

```
Example, you might wamt to set
    _reasonTable.Asset = NoYes::No;
instead of
    _reasonTable.Asset = NoYes::Yes;
```

**Call createReason() function in the setUpTestCase() and reasons are inserted into database.**

That's all. Hope that it helps someone at some point of time.

Be happy.

> ~Shakir Shabbir

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the setUp() and tearDown() methods on the test class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb496539.aspx

You can create data before the test class execution and delete it when testing ends.

Comment: Yes, I am aware about those methods. But I want to know how can we insert Reasons in ReasonTable for Assets.